# Android Studio GoogleMaps in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to put the map of Google Maps in my sección with marks and my localitation, but when i put this section, this app closes. And It says ERROR MapFragment.java:83 " LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat("Lat")".
I put my two code's files:

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapFragment.java**

```
package com.example.julianrc1.petracecitm;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {


    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;


    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle                                                                          savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mMapView= (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;


                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        //Request location updates:
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }


                markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat("Lat"),                                                                                     Float.parseFloat("Long"));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).
                        title("Title").snippet("TitleName"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition =                                                                           new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition
                        (cameraPosition ));



            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]
                                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        1);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {



                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Thank you so much for help me!!!

Comment: Float.parseFloat("Lat")? How do you think this is valid? Parsing characters as float will always throw exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat("Lat")
```

with

```
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(33.8688,151.2093)
```